# How can i ignore only two particular files from a project, form being updated and committed, in Netbeans?

Tags: svn

I want to ignore only two files in my SVN, I am using Netbeans. These both are the config.php files located at different locations in same project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your working copy, go to the parent directory of both of these `config.php` files, and set the `svn:ignore` property on those directories to `config.php`.

```
cd dir1 # assuming dir1/config.php is one of the files to ignore
svn propset svn:ignore config.php .
# repeat for dir2
```

Don't forget to commit!